# ruamel.yaml ReaderError when trying to load special characters (Non-whitespace controls)

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

Trying to load the [big-list-of-naughty-strings](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings/blob/master/blns.txt) into Python using ruamel.yaml (to test the character set for an API).

Everything was loaded fine except the 2 lines: 115 and 120 (94 and 95 in the [json](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings/blob/master/blns.json) version).

In comments they were described as 'Non-whitespace C0 controls' and 'Non-whitespace C1 controls'.

Example:

```
>>> from ruamel.yaml import YAML
>>> ruamel_yaml = YAML()
>>> ruamel_yaml.load('\u000f')
...
ruamel.yaml.reader.ReaderError: unacceptable character #x000f: special characters are not allowed
  in "<unicode string>", position 0
```

Wondering if this could be a bug or an expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not consulted the [character set chapter](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2770814) in the YAML specification:

> The allowed character range explicitly excludes the C0 control block #x0-#x1F (except for TAB #x9, LF #xA, and CR #xD which are allowed), DEL #x7F, the C1 control block #x80-#x9F (except for NEL #x85 which is allowed), the surrogate block #xD800-#xDFFF, #xFFFE, and #xFFFF.

Line 115 are the C0 controls, and line 120 the C1 controls, so it should be no surprise that those lines don't load.

Comment: Thanks, they also have a [base64](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings/blob/master/blns.base64.txt) version, so using it to load some special characters into Python would be a solution I guess.

Comment: Yes that is a separate question. Make sure to format the code correctly, provide the contents of the output file, reference the spec why the output is invalid.